# How is the maximum price level determined in Theme Hospital?

Tags: theme-hospital

In the original theme hospital, patients will not come and refuse to be treated if you raise your prices above a certain level.

For example: At the default 100%, I have never had problems. Setting it to 120% at the start will net you zero clients.

How is this variable determined (for each type of cure)? I'd like to know or reconstruct an exact formula or a close match.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some preliminary investigative work, and in reality, it's not actually quite so simple: there's no 'set'  price everyone will pay: each patient seems to have its own payment tolerance.

It appears true that even as low as 105%, some patients will refuse to pay at the base reputation level. At 145% it appears no one will allow treatment anymore, while with the 100 measurements done so far the in-between formula appears linear.

E.g. at 145% price there's a 0% admission rate, at 100% it's 100% and the rate is linear in between (at 130% price you should see 1 in 3 patients continuing).

There's some avenues to explore next;

- study the effects of reputation
- inspect the game's code to see if we can learn more from it.
- take more measurements to get a statistically sound result